# Translating a simple for loop into a while loop?

Tags: c++, loops

How can I write this same code with the while loop instead of the for loop?

```
int n;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = n; j >= i; j--) {
            cout << j;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

This is my attempt, but it does not achieve the same affect. I'm not sure why.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int i = 1;
int j = n;

    while (i <= n) {
        while (j >= i) {
            cout << j;
            j--;
        }
        i++;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: the `int j = n;` has to go in between loops

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset `j` before the `while(j >= i)` loop.

```
while (i <= n) {
    j = n;   //<<<<<<<< Reset j to the starting value
    while (j >= i) {
        cout << j;
        j--;
    }
    i++;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thank you.